# Dual boot with multiple drives

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, multi-boot

I just built a new desktop with 4 internal drives total, with the thought to have a dual boot Linux/Windows workstation with two drives dedicated to each. How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Just like everyone else, with **GRUB**. https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html

Comment: Another approach - I use it myself - is to adopt one system as your main system and then have the other system as a virtual machine. I have both Windows and Linux as virtual and Windows 10 as Host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Bootloaders - Bootloaders are executable code called by the computers BIOS.  Typically these then load an operating system.  Most Linux distributions use Grub2, however there are others.  Windows uses the Windows Boot Manager.  They are installed with the operating system, often overwriting any previous one.  However, they are usually capable of booting other operating systems.  I would recommend install Windows first, then install Linux.  Grub2 will detect Windows and overwrite its Windows Boot Manager with Grub2, but will detect it and allow you to boot Windows.
2. BIOS - You can install multiple operating systems and bootloaders on separate drives.  Many BIOSs will let you hit a key and select a specific drive to boot from.  This allows you to keep the bootloaders from overwriting each other, if that is something you are looking to do.  This is the method I use, as I use many operating systems on many removable drives.

Comment: I think I will try to do your second option, as I have had some trouble in the past with dual boot from a single drive using Grub, where Windows updates would mess with the boot record.

Answer (score 0):

You should want to install Windows first, then use the LICK to install the Linux from within Windows.
There are different flavors to Linux so watch the Legacy and/or UEFI on the package, depending which BIOS you have and choose to use. Windows 10 only like to use UEIF.

https://github.com/noryb009/lick

How to Install Puppy Linux in Dual Boot Mode on Windows 10 PC
https://www.trishtech.com/2016/09/install-puppy-linux-in-dual-boot-mode-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

By "dedicated", I assume that you want each operating system can work independently as long as their dedicated drives are up.

The easiest way to achieve this is installing Windows with 2 drives attached. Then remove them, connect the other 2 to install Linux. This way, the installer won't detect an existing EFI system partition created by the another OS, and creates another one on their disk.

After connecting all 4 drives, your mobo BIOS should detect both bootloaders automatically. Some server mobos don't, and you have to add them into the EFI boot entry manually.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant. Would I need to do anything with the second drive though disk management that is not used by the OS before moving onto Linux?